# Problem with instance of class while creating reusable controller in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, oop, scalability, reusability

I want to reuse all my servise and controllers and I was achieving this with extending class.
I'm calling the class of Controller and service all the way up from a router.
everything looks fine while creating instance of class,
but when I send request to sign in route it says there is no this.servise or this.dto which is i passed to the constructor while creating this instance of object

```
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();
import UserController from "../../controllers/user.controller";
import UserService from "../../services/user.service.js";
import {UserDto} from "../../dtos/user.dto.js";
import User from "../../models/User.js";

const userService = new UserService(User);
console.log(userService, UserDto);                             // successfully logged
const userController = new UserController(userService, UserDto);
console.log(userController);                                   // successfully logged
router.post('/signup', userController.signup);
router.post('/signin', userController.signIn);
router.post('/signout', userController.signOut);
router.get('/all', userController.getAll);

router.route("/:id")
    .get(userController.get)
    .post(userController.create)
    .patch(userController.update)
    .delete(userController.delete);

export default router;
```

```
export default class UserController extends MainController {
    async signIn(req, res) {
        try {
            const {email, password} = req.body;//await this.dto.login(req.body);
            const result = await this.service.signIn(email, password); // TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'service')
            return res.status(201).json({message: "successfully signed in", token: result.token, user: this.dto.output(result.user)});
        }
        catch(err){
            sendError(res, err);
        }
    }
```

I've reviewed my knowledge of how nodejs modules work, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Who can explain me this situation, please!?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You didn't define a constructor in UserController to set the field...

Comment: I did it MainController class and i did it too here with super when i tried to fix the issue, but it didn't help

Comment: Where is your call to super? I can't see it in your code (?). Perhaps also share the super class.

Comment: There's no need for a call to `super` if you don't have a constructor defined. I assume that `MainController` has an appropriate constructor...

Comment: yeah MainController has it. I just forget to bind, my question is answered thank you all for helping me guys!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `.bind()` when passing the references to the methods to the Express router. So who knows what the value of `this` will be when Express tries to call them (in JS, `this` doesn't work like other variable names, it doesn't use lexical scoping, what the value will be depends on the calling code).

Change your code to e.g.

```
router.post('/signup', userController.signup.bind(userController));
```

This will ensure that `this` is set to your `userController` object when the function gets called (`bind()` is a method available on all function objects that returns a new function with a fixed `this` value).

Comment: yeah, thank you it works, do you any efficient idea for not repeating all binds

Comment: Not really :( personally I just don't do it like that, I don't use classes, just modules and normal functions... and since there's no "this" in them (just references to module-level variables), I also don't need "bind"...

Comment: Ok, thank you!. I was using modules too, but I like classes from other language :-)